# How to animate the ImageJ stack window

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

I am trying to animate the ImageJ stack window with the following code which resides in my customizedGUI class:

```
ImageCanvas ic = new ImageCanvas(image);
StackWindow sw = new StackWindow(image,ic);
panel2.add(sw.getContentPane());
sw.setAnimate(true);
//sw.run();
//sw.getAnimate();
```

When I run this class it displays the stack window which only displays the first image out of 100 images that are opened in my internal frame within my desktop pane but it does not animate it. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of [`StackWindow.java`](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/master/ij/gui/StackWindow.java#L295-299), I would conclude that `sw.setAnimate(true)` merely updates a `boolean` and redraws the button of a `ScrollbarWithLabel` instance.

To animate your stack, you'd have to use the [`ij.plugin.Animator`](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/master/ij/plugin/Animator.java) class:

```
import ij.plugin.Animator;

new Animator.run("start");
```

However, this class makes use of the ImageJ GUI via `WindowManager`, so you might have to re-implement its methods if you really want to code your own GUI.

Good luck, hope that helps.